# Ark symbols meanning

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

[image]

I was playing ark and I finally managed to get a good connection and downloaded the update for ark, now when I try and play it it has the bank status effect at the bottom and the pickaxe and shovel at the top.

What does this icon mean?

Answer (score 2):

That icon means you are currently targeting something that may be mined/harvested for materials. A similar icon that works the same way is the hand icon that shows up when you are currently targeting something that can be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

For a list of status-effects and what they mean, see https://ark.gamepedia.com/Status_Effects. The house-icon indicates you're in a building and get extra protection to temperature-effects. The icon on the left-bottom indicates that there's a storm and it's not advised to visit a desert-region.